# displaying images in android with zoom/pan/rotate etc functionality

Tags: android

So i got a lot of solutions online but none of them were simple and complete. First i tried using imageview and adding external libraries for zooming etc. but i couldn't find one which had all the functionality we see in a gallery app without being extremely slow. I read something about canvas though don't know what it is. I also found "zooming a view" in android official tutorial but it was just a single tap zoom. So which is the best solution (in terms of functionality and speed) for this: I want an activity to show just a single image such that the user can zoom/rotate/pan it as its gonna contain text that the user needs to be able to read. So basically just like a gallery app. Is it possible to call on the gallery app activity to display this image? Why doesnt android have better support to do this? What is the best way you would suggest.

Comment: check this link for guidance -- http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/